# Graph API : Change plan name - patch syntax

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to change the title of a plan via Powershell but I don't seem to get it right:

1)I start by adding the Authorization token and etag in the headers:

```
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("If-Match",'etag goes here')
$headers.Add('Authorization',"Bearer $accessToken")
```

2)Declaring the new title

```
$newtitle = @{title = 'The new title'}
$json = $newtitle | ConvertTo-Json
```

3) Making the call to the api

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/task-id"
    $edittask = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers  @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"} -Uri $url -Method 'PATCH' -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $json
```

This fails with a 412 - Precondition Failed , any ideas on what am I missing?

Comment: are you trying to update the name of a plan or task? The url in step 3 is for a task-id, but you mentioned updating the title of a plan.

Comment: Good point , both actually , apologies for the confusion .

Comment: One thing that often trips people up with ETags is that they should be quoted with double quotes.  I'm not sure if Graph is picky about this, but it might be worth ensuring that your etag value in the if-match header is surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,I assume you want to update a plan or task.

Refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/planner_overview#common-planner-error-conditions)，`412 status code can be returned if the etag value specified in the request no longer matches a version of the resource in the service. In this case, the clients should read the resource again and obtain a new etag`.

So we should read the resource again and obtain a new etag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I'm using the etag I take from the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{task-id}/details , isn't that the right one?

Comment: your reply definitely gave me a clue, I was retrieving the etag with Graph Explorer, then manually copying and pasting that etag to my script to make the change, that didn't work - not sure why. If I first retrieve the same etag programmatically then pass the etag to my patch action it works just fine.